# copy the tables after execution

Tags: sql

I would like to create new table after executing that query

```
create table newTable as select * from oldTable
```

However, this does not appear to work. How do I get the new table after executing some queries?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: "*does not appear to work*" is not a valid error message in *any* DBMS.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what DBMS you are using or what errors you are getting, so I will try to answer for multiple systems.

If you are working with Oracle or PostgreSQL (there might be some other systems that this rule applies to), your syntax seems to be correct. Just make sure your new table doesn't exist yet - otherwise it's going to error out. In case if you  are trying to insert into an existing table - which I don't think the case is, however - you can try something like -

```
INSERT INTO newTable SELECT * FROM oldTable
```

On the other hand, if you are working with T-SQL (SQL Server), you could SELECT INTO the new table. The new table will be created with the old table's schema.

You can read more about the INTO Clause at [MSDN Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188029%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Your code should look like -

```
SELECT *
INTO newTable 
FROM oldTable
```

And, specifying the column names and filters also works the similar way -

```
SELECT  Column1, Column2, Column3, ...
INTO    newTable 
FROM    oldTable
WHERE   <Filter Condition>
```

Whatever the case is, you would get more help if you specify the details.

Comment: @MeNoMore: Of course, the INTO keyword is to create a new table. If you run the query while the newTable exists, that would throw an error.

Comment: What if Jays isn't using SQL Server? The ANSI SQL standard specifies the syntax he/she is using.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: edited my answer, hopefully this is more helpful.

Comment: It's not only Oracle which complies with the standard syntax. PostgreSQL and others do as well. And besides: PL/SQL is **only** for stored procedures. Outside of stored procedures it's simply called SQL.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax in general is like:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table
  AS (SELECT * FROM old_table);
```

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE suppliers
  AS (SELECT id, address, city, state, zip
      FROM companies
      WHERE id > 1000);
```

Try removing the stars (*) and add the brackets.

Read [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/tables/create_table2.php) for more examples.

Comment: The brackets around the select are not necessary and the `*` won't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

As You Said you want to copy the values into new table after execution 
whether if you are running the stored procedure using cursor let the cursor  shuld be closed then use query as follows

Select * into Table1 from Table2

if you want to copy selected colums go for

Select Coloumn1 ,column2,... into table1 from table 2 where ............